# Changing checkbox of column type DataGridCheckBoxColumn using DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I currently have another issue opened related to the DataGrid but I thought I'd open another 
I'm trying to change the status of a checkbox automatically based on the value of another column, but how do I do this using the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`? I was using the 'IsSelected' but eventually realized this property applied to the cell rather than the checkbox.

Here's my code

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive}">
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="01" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="03" >
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

As you can see, I want to select the checkbox automatically when the LocationText is 2 and unselect it when the LocationText is 3.

Any ideas?

**Update 1:**

I thought I figured it out when I tried the following:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="01" >
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="02" >
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLocation.LocationText}" Value="03" >
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

But to no avail. It disables the checkbox alright but it refuses to check it.

Frustrating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                        <CheckBox Name="cbxAll">
                            <CheckBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=wndMain, Path=LocationText , Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="" >
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=wndMain, Path=LocationText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="01" >
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=wndMain, Path=LocationText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="02" >
                                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=wndMain, Path=LocationText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="03" >
                                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </CheckBox.Style>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

and datacontext must be implement INotifyPropertyChanged
and when binded property changed it needs to notify property changed.

Comment: I've just updated my question with what I thought was going to be a solution, but still not working. Will give your example a shot and see how I get on. Looks very similar to what I've just posted, so I don't know if it will work, but touch wood!

Comment: I've just noticed that you're not using the DataGridCheckBoxColumn. Any particular reason?

Comment: Yes but i am using datatemplate with checkbox that you can use instead.

Comment: I got it to work with your sample but I HATE giving up, so I'll keep trying for a while to get it to work with the DataGridCheckBoxColumn. I'm looking at another problem at the moment where all my rows are being updated to the same value but I'll update the answer as soon as I have more.

Comment: Ok, it's the closest I've got it to work using your method, but I'm still having one problem. I have to click away on another row for the change to be committed to my ViewModel. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by changing.You mean change the data in the row you click?

Comment: No, the IsChecked checkbox property is binded to a property in my RowViewModel and when the checkbox is selected, it should update my property with the value from IsChecked but it doesn't kick in until I click on another row.

Comment: Ahh I got it, so you can call NotifySourceUpdated=true and NotifyTArgetUpdated= true and updateSourceTrigger = propertyChanged by the way don't forget the binding mode two way you use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123008/discussion-between-thierry-and-freeman).